# How to build a linux for Intel galileo gen 2?

Tags: linux, arduino, yocto, intel-galileo

[There're some files](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=galileo), provided by intel. It is set of linux images for Intel galileo. I tryed to build one of them with help of [this thing](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/), but it doesn't work, because image doesn't consist .bb file which is the target file for bitbake. Could you explain how to build one of those images? I need it to boot this on galileo.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you familiar with BuildRoot, you may use special set of scripts to achieve that: https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/tree/intel/board/intel/common

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search of "galileo gen 2 yocto" brought up many guides of how to build a Yocto image for what you are asking for.